# Best practice for OAuth Tokens for a combination of native apps and backend processes

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, backend, mobile-application

I have a scenario in which a mobile (native) app is requiring data from a long running task. The task is a continuesly running on the users behalf, and we have decided to move it to a backend service. To execute the task, the backend service must regularly fetch data from an API that is OAuth2 protected.

Our dilemma is that we are not sure how to provide the backend service with a set of access tokens to access the data API. Our mobile app uses the OAuth2 Authorization Grant flow with PKCS to get its own access token, refresh token and id-token (we use OpenID Connect). But how do we provide our backend service with a set of tokens? As the backend is continuesly running (also in absence of the mobile native app) we would like to provide it with its own set of access/refresh tokens.

There seem to be several solutions:

- Proxy all mobile app communication to external APIs via the backend, make the client a private client, use the authorization code flow, and setup custom login sessions between the native app and our backend. To me this means more running backend infrastructure, and implementing session management including session refresh, etc. which is like re-implementing the OpenId flows on my own servers...
- Using OpenID hybrid flow, providing both an access token as well as an authorization code to be shared with the backend. However, this seems to be directed at (in-browser) web-apps, not so much native mobile apps as it based on the implicit flow and as such less secure.
- Doing the authorization code flow twice on the mobile app (optionally second time with prompt=none to suppress user interaction), keeping one code for the app, forwarding the second to the backend. Then both backend and app can exchange their own codes for access tokens. This feels a bit like a hack as the backend should be a private client, not a public client. It is the approach that Google seems to advertise though in CrossClientAuth
- Performing impersonation by sending the id-token to the backend which then exchanges that id-token for its own set of access/refresh tokens. Microsoft does this through the jwt-bearer grant in its "on-behalf-of" scenarios. Moreover, the token-exchange RFC seems to cover the same use-case. However, in this scenario the id-token is indirectly used as access credential, not just as a bag of claims about the user identity, which is odd in my view as access should be controlled through access tokens, is it not? Moreover, not all services should be allowed to impersonate, so I suppose this comes with additional configuration complexity.

To me it feels that I'm overlooking something, this must be a problem others have too and must have been solved before... What would be best practice in my situation?